# Reading Memory Stick Pro Duo in a N76VZ laptop

Tags: sd-card, memorystick

I have a MS Pro Duo card taken from a Sony digital camera to read. I don't currently have a camera cable for that model, and in one day I'll be able to return the camera to its owner for photo downloading.

But, with only my laptop and unwilling to buy adapters, I'd like to download my pictures **right now**, if possible.

Basically I have an Asus N76VZ laptop equipped with a *card reader*. I wanted to show you a photo of this card reader (not taken with **that** camera of course) but I couldn't get a decent one. Anyway it's a SD hole with the following text on its left

```
MMC, SD, MS/PRO
```

From what I can understand it reads Memory Stick Pro, so the question comes straight: **is it compatible with MS Pro *Duo***? I tried to gently insert the card but I found it's quite a short card so I didn't attempt to enter it deeplier in order to avoid breaking the reader.

Otherwise, if I can't find a USB MS Pro Duo reader somewhere in the office, is there any adapter that *can* be used to read such a card in a SD reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need such an adapter to insert it in your existing card reader:

[image]

Comment: This adapter looks as narrow as the card, and definitely narrower than the card hole. If I understand correctly, being longer allows it to enter deeper into the reader's hole, am I correct?

Comment: The adapter is longer and thicker. If you try to put the MS Pro Duo without the adapter in the slot, it wont fit.